# How to enable auto complete for a list of files in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I tried to get all the ".txt" files on the user's desktop and display them in the `ComboBox` as a custom source, as shown below. By the way I created the `ComboBox` through IDE. The code below is within the `form1_Load` event:

```
string desktop_path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string[] files_on_desktop = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(desktop_path, "*.txt");
AutoCompleteStringCollection file_collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
file_collection.AddRange(files_on_desktop);
comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = file_collection;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

This seems not to work although I tried in many different ways as well as with many supporting code such as "`this.Refresh()` or `combobox.Refresh()`".

It doesn't show files when I open drop-down, also it doesn't show files when I start typing.

Actually, whenever I try to do things dynamically which I can do on IDE, I got some sort of problems.

Comment: It works properly. What do you expect that you say *This seems not to work*?

Comment: Those files which you added include path and file name, for example *C:\Users\R.Aghaei\Desktop\Test.txt*.  If you need to see only filename, add `.Select(x=>System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray()` after `GetFiles`. This way file names will be used for auto complete. Also if you want to show those filenames just for autocomplete, a `TextBox` is enough. If you want to use a `ComboBox` it's better to add those files to `Items` collection and then set `AutoCompleteSourceMode` to `AutoCompleteSource.ListItems`.

Comment: OK.  with your explanation which made the situation clear, now it shows the file names after I start typing. 

On the other hand, I know this could also be done with a textbox. However, to be more specific, what I want to do is to preview all possible options by clicking the drop down utility even before typing the file name, but nothing appears in the drop down list. I could not figure out using Items, if that would work. Please explain further if possible.

Comment: `AutoCompleteSource` is different from `Items`. You should add those file names to `Items` to be shown when you click on drop down button. To do so, just use `comboBox1.Items.AddRange(files_on_desktop);`. Then just set `AutoCompleteSourceMode` to `AutoCompleteSource.ListItems`. Then you have both items and auto complete. If you click on drop down button, you will see all available items. If you only type in the box, auto-complete will work for you.

Comment: problem solved. thanks

Comment: yes I would ask you about it indeed. but I thought I could not check a comment-style answer. your whole answer below is now checked ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files which you added include path and file name, for example *C:\Users\R.Aghaei\Desktop\Test.txt*. If you need to see only filename, you can use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)` to get file names only.

Also if you want to show those filenames just for autocomplete, a `TextBox` would be enough. If you want to use a `ComboBox` it's better to add those files to Items collection and then set auto complete source to list items.

`AutoCompleteSource` is different from `Items`. You should add those file names to `Items` to be shown when you click on drop down button. To do so, just use `comboBox1.Items.AddRange(files_on_desktop);`. Then just set `AutoCompleteSourceMode` to `AutoCompleteSource.ListItems`. Then you have both items and auto complete. If you click on drop down button, you will see all available items. If you only type in the box, auto-complete will work for you.

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(desktopPath, "*.txt")
                                .Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```